# Docker Hub Update Notifications

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

Are there any good methods/tools to get notifications on updates to containers on Docker Hub? Just to clarify, I don't want to automatically update, just somehow be notified of updates.

I'm currently running a [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) cluster so if I could just specify a list of containers (as opposed to it using the ones on my system) that would be great.

Comment: i am guessing you wan to update base images. I can see it may be useful to be notified. i guess an easy trick is to pull latest and grep for the response which will tell you if the image was updated. but i don't thin dockerhub has hooks otherwise.

Comment: @MrE Yeah, I was looking for an easy way to find which base containers I need to update

Comment: dockerhub has hooks if you own the repo, but if you don't you only option is to pull

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [docker-notify](https://github.com/Schlabbi/docker-notify)?  It runs on Node (perhaps imperfect).. but within it's own container.  You'll need a mailserver or a webhook for it to trigger against.

I'm surprised this isn't supported by *docker.exe* or *Docker-hub*.. base image changes (eg *Alpine*) cause a lot of churn with both hub-dependent (*Nginx*, *Postgres*) and local dependent containers possibly needing rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I also found myself needing this, so I helped build [image-watch.com](https://image-watch.com), which is a subscription-based service that watches Docker images and sends notifications when they are updated. As a hosted service, it's not free, but we tried to make it as cheap as possible.